# How to impute the missing value on the test set?

Tags: data-science, missing-data

I am now handling the missing data. I have missing data in my test and train set. I got a little confused about how to deal with the missing data in the **test** set. If I am imputing by using the "mean" method, should I use the mean calculated from the train set or the test set if I want to impute the missing value in the **test** set. 
Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, you should not compute mean or anything other from test set (best way of thinking about test set is that it simply doesn't exist, at least until you have already trained your model).

Build a transformation pipeline that can handle all the necessary preprocessing steps (impute missing data, standardize, perform desired feature engineering, dimensionality reduction...) on training set and when a new observation comes (we should treat test set as just a new observations that are unavailable during training) apply this pipeline transformations on that new data.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `train` mean for that. You should never infer information from `test` dataset as that's an information leak.

Calculating mean of `test` dataset would give your algoritm info about `mean` of it (obviously) and would probably falsely improve its score on said.

In real life you would usually have no way to calculate mean of missing data anyway (think of single incoming example with missing values).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am still a little bit confused that would it be a data-leakage since the imputed values were calculated based on the train set and will cause the training precision to go high? Thanks again!

Comment: If you calculate them over `train` there is not data leakage, there would be if you calculated them over `test`.